# How do I represent a world and dynamic objects in a C++ console game?

Tags: c++, oop

I'd appreciate some help with a small project of mine. It's supposed to be a console game, using elements from roguelikes, RPGs, sandboxes and survival games.

I have attempted about three times so far to get a working architecture. Each time, I hit problems I couldn't solve without hacking my way around it...

I already looked at numerous blogs and tutorials for this, but none of them fit my purpose exactly.

1) http://trystans.blogspot.co.at/2011/08/roguelike-tutorial-01-java-eclipse.html
2) http://www.kathekonta.com/rlguide/index.html

I have already followed Trystan's blog - who uses Java - and recreated his design in Java and AS3.
However, I wasn't quite content with the way he linked the classes together. Commands like World.dig() - To me, it makes more sense to call Player.dig() - or the map representation as a 3d(!) array made me believe that there must be a better way to do this.

The second link I posted is coded in C++, however, there is only one central map. My goal is to be able to have multiple maps, which I can enter with characters, etc.

I will post the code of my newest attempt below. It doesn't feature any movement or interaction at all, since I want to get the design right from the beginning, not failing after hours spent into the project (which I already encountered way too often).

**main.cpp:**

```
# include <iostream>

# include "World.h"
# include "Entity.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int testFloor[] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    World world(testFloor, 5, 5);

    //Creating an entity at the top left corner 
    Entity nine(9, 0);
    world.addEntity(nine);

    //Draw the entire world
    world.draw(0,0,5,5); 

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**World.h:**

```
# ifndef WORLD_H
# define WORLD_H

# include <vector>

# include "Entity.h"

using namespace std;

class World {
private:
    int* _floor;
    int _width;
    int _height;

    vector<Entity> _entities;

public:
    World(int* floor, int width, int height) :
        _floor(floor), _width(width), _height(height){}

    /*Pushes an Entity to the _entities-vector*/
    void addEntity(Entity e){
        _entities.push_back(e);
    }

    /*Displays the floor at a position, or the glyph of an entity, if applicable*/
    //This "glyph" is just a number here, similar to the contents of the _floor array
    int glyph(int ID){
        int out = _floor[ID];
        for(Entity e : _entities){
            if(e.pos() == ID){
                out = e.glyph();
                break;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    //Prints the World as seen from "above" - entities will cover the floor
    void draw(int left, int top, int width, int height){
        system("cls");

        int ID;

        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                ID = (x+left)+(y+top)*width;
                cout << glyph(ID);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};

# endif
```

**Entity.h:**

```
# ifndef ENTITY_H
# define ENTITY_H

class Entity{
private:
    int _glyph; //Will be a char later, integer for now, since the glyph function returns
                //an int for simplicity
    int _pos;

public:
    Entity(int glyph, int pos) : _glyph(glyph), _pos(pos) {}

    int glyph(){return _glyph;}
    int pos(){return _pos;}
};

# endif
```

The code compiles and works. A new Entity is spawned at the top left, represented by a "9", the map is drawn as expected and all... but I'm seeing problems even right now.

1) As I create a new Entity, I need to give it the ID (Worldposition) to spawn at - however it has no clue about its actual position in the world.

2) Whenever the Entity would move, it would need a reference to the map it is on, in order to know, where it's going.

To solve these problems, it would probably be beneficial to store a reference to the world inside the Entity.
However, I want to be able to perform a command like World.update(), which automatically updates all the Entities, giving them the opportunity to move, attack, open doors, build barricades, ... The world would then iterate through all the entities, calling their respective update functions.

I found out from a previous attempt, that it causes problems to store a reference to a world in the entity class, and storing an array/vector of entities inside the world class.

So here are my actual questions:
- How can I design my classes in order to have a meaningful relationship between Entities and the World(s)?
 - Where do I put my references - directly into function calls, maybe (that's going to cost performance, I guess)?

Edit: Please note, that I'm not expecting code samples, I rather want to write the code myself. What would help me most would be hints such as which class should hold which variables.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: "I found out from a previous attempt, that it causes problems to store a reference to a world in the entity class, and storing an array/vector of entities inside the world class." - could you elaborate on that? Also note that "reference" has a very specific meaning in C++, which might differ from the way you use the term in other languages.

Comment: Instead of the tricky "A has a reference to B" you can more safely say "A refers to B" or more generally "A depends on B"

Comment: @lethal-guitar: I was talking about the & - Operator, such as World& world, in order to store the world as a reference.

Comment: @Kos: English is not my first language, so I might not express myself in the most straight-forward way... I thought by using the word "reference" explicitly, it would be easier to understand what I meant.
Feel free to change my original post, if it improves overall readability :)

Comment: @Edi ok, just wanted to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: @lethal-guitar: I believe we are ^^
As far as my previous attempt is concerned - it had a lot of additional code, and I'm not sure, how to provide a sample without cluttering the original question. Basically, each entity had a World& world reference, and as I tried to store entities inside the world class as vector<Entity> entities, nothing worked anymore. The compiler threw errors like "expected ";" after &" - Which was the main reason why I restarted from scratch and trying to find my design flaws in advance.

Comment: @Edi It's hard to tell what problem you were facing (maybe circular references?), but it's definitely possible to do it that way.

Comment: @Edi, On your last comment - Try not to mix compiler errors with bad design. It might be that your design was fine, and you just had a small error in the code.

Comment: @lethal-guitar: Yes. I believe "circular reference" is exactly the term. From what I've learned, it's best to avoid them at all. To quote some article, which source I've forgot... "If you only change your code to keep the compiler happy, rethink your design" - which is what I did.

Comment: @Edi [Here is my answer](https://stackedit.io/viewer#!provider=gist&gistId=a8d64fce36b2844ec7b1&filename=How%20do%20I%20represent%20a%20world%20and%20dynamic%20objects%20in%20a%20C%2B%2B%20console%20game%3F)

Comment: I would suggest you compile error regarding the World& was because you needed a forward declaration in entity.h for the World class.

Comment: @Kos: Very nice read, thanks for the elaboration! I'd like to follow the concept of disconnecting graphics from the object logic, but I'm not sure, *how* to actually achieve this. If the Entities don't store their locations, who does? It would be great, if you could provide any links to read more about this method.

Comment: @Pete: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind. For now, I'll try to get it working with your answer (passing object references to functions). I can always recycle my old code, too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If I understand your question right, in order to find your 2d position on the map from your 1d coordinate, you can use something like the following:

```
Point Entity::pos2D(World& world) const {
    int y = _pos / world.width();
    int x = _pos % world.width();
    return Point(x, y);
}
```

Assuming you have a Point class to aggregate x and y.  Also adding width() and height() accessor functions to the World object here.

You may fnd, however that it is better to store a 2d position in the first place - calculating the 1d position from it would involve a multiply instead of a divide.

2) You could pass in a reference to the world in the various entity manipulation member functions.  e.g.

```
Entity::update(World& world) {
   // do some stuff
}
Entity::move(World& world) {
   // do some stuff
}
```

This will save storing a pointer to the world in every entity.  This will reduce memory usage and also give better locality of reference.  i.e. if you have many entities then it will probably improve performance by having more complete entities in the processor cache, depending upon how they are stored.  I would not be worrying about performance at this stage too much though.

Comment: 1) I do know how to translate between 1d and 2d, but thanks for elaborating :)
2) Yes, that's actually quite close to what I'm trying to achieve.
So, you are proposing to pass the reference to each function call, rather than saving it within the entity... As you already stated, performance isn't too important right now, but would this cause problems eventually?

Comment: r.e. 2) I would - it is more flexible,

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it that way right now.
I'll accept the answer as soon as I succeeded =)
(I also edited my comment above - since you mentioned performance, would passing references through functions be a problem with let's say 1000 entities?)

Comment: I very much doubt it unless you are compiling for a 1980s casio calculator.  The only way to know is to profile the code, but I would suggest that for a decent optimizing compiler and a modern CPU with instruction pipe-lining, the function call parameter method is likely to perform marginally better, although your number of objects is so small that it is going to be completely unnoticeable to the player.

Comment: @Edi there's not much difference - either you pass the reference explicitly as argument, or implicitly via `this` pointer.. It will make a difference in memory consumption, but not in speed. And, as Pete already said, 1000 entities are not many.

Comment: The main difference being that the 'world' pointer is likely to be on the stack or in a register already.  If this is duplicated in part of a heap-allocated Entity then that implies getting hold of the pointer from memory.  If not in the cache then it affects performance.  Having said that, for 1000 small objects they are likely to all end up in the cache.  If the objects are more complicated to deal with then it will dwarf any performance gain of parameter vs member

Comment: Having said that, you'll still need to access the memory of the Entity, so make it as small as possible so more of them will fit in a processor cache line if in contiguous memory.  To be honest though its fairly pointless to worry about it too much - I can;t see this being a performance bottleneck in your final game.

Comment: If you were to profile your code now, you'd probably see that using cout takes the vast majority of CPU time.

Comment: I know... the console is not exactly suited for such usage. I want to avoid external libraries for now. Chances are, that I'll look deeper into the ncurses-library. I just want to have the basic architecture down first.

In any case, I want to thank everyone of you for your help and information. I should be able to build on that =)